# How do I give a value to an href as its done to a submit?

Tags: php, html

I named a submit and an href and when I test the conditions submit works but the href does not and there is no error displayed . Please any help will be appreciated 
Bellow is the code

```
<form action="test.php" method="post"/>
<a href="#" name="amhref" >Href</a>
<input type ="submit" name="button"  value="button">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['amhref'])){
echo ("<h1>I am href </h1>");
}else if(isset($_POST['button'])){
echo ("<h1>I am the button</h1>");
}
?>
```

Comment: An `<a>` is not a form element. It won't be submitted.

Comment: is not available to do this  you must use `form` tag like `input` for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a link `<a>` is not sent with a form. so any data you would like to pass should be done through the href field. this is done with a get method, so please note the $_GET

```
<form action="test.php" method="post"/>
<input type ="submit" name="button"  value="button">
</form>
<a href="?amhref" name="amhref" >Href</a>
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['amhref'])){
    echo ("<h1>I am href </h1>");
  }else if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    echo ("<h1>I am the button</h1>");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Answere worked 100% and thanks for explaining am gonna tick after 7 minutes pass

Answer (score 1):

Using an `<input>` control to achieve this. I have used a hidden control.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id1" value="hello">
```

**You can't do with an `<a>` tag**

Answer (score 1):

tag not element of form type so that you cant pass to in form submite. If you want to pass keep amhref value in input type text or Hidden.

You can pass value with href with GET method also.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post"/>
<input type ="submit" name="button"  value="button">
</form>
<a href="?amhref" name="amhref" >Href</a>

<?php
  if(isset($_GET['amhref'])){
    echo ("<h1>I am href </h1>");
  }else if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    echo ("<h1>I am the button</h1>");
  }
```